# How can we use the number of crossovers per chromosome to calculate the recombination rate in cM / Mb?

Tags: recombination, genetic-linkage, crossover

I was reading a paper titled "Tetrad analysis in plants and fungi finds large differences in gene conversion rates but no GC bias" (2018). According to this paper:

"The between-species differences in CO rates reflect in part the fact that each chromosome needs at least one chiasmata. Indeed, the CO rates are more uniform when expressed as CO events per chromosome with about an order of magnitude difference in cM Mb-1 per chromosome: from ~5.3 COs per chromosome in yeast (= 22 cM Mb-1 per chromosome, N = 16) to ~2.3 COs per chromosome in Neurospora (= 2.8 cM Mb-1 per chromosome, N = 7), to ~2.2 COs per chromosome in Arabidopsis (= 0.9 cM Mb-1 per chromosome, N = 5) to ~1.4 COs per chromosome in Chlamydomonas (= 0.7 cM Mb-1 per chromosome, N = 17)."

Here, the authors give 1) the number of crossovers per chromosome in each of these four species and 2) the equivalent recombination rate in units of cM / Mb. However, I don't understand how the conversion was reached in each case.

Take *Chlamydomonas reinhardtii* for example, with 1.4 COs per chromosome. There are 17 chromosomes, so that's 23.8 total crossover events. (Roughly agrees with Table 1.) The whole genome is ~110 Mb, so that's 0.216 CO / Mb. And ... I am unsure how to proceed. It's just not clear to me how to complete the conversion for any of these organisms. How can I calculate the recombination rate in cM / Mb, as the authors of this paper did, from the number of crossover events?